# I use NOT IN to compare and object's id to a list of ids. Comparison seems to always evaluate to TRUE

Tags: python, arraylist, comparison

Consider the following Code in Python 3.8:

```
def clean_data(data) -> list:
    """Takes a list of Webelements and extracts needed information using RegEx.
        Groups Information into Dictionarys.
        Returns List of Dictionarys"""
    clean_data = []

    for element in data:

        datapoint = {}
        text = element.text

        name = re.search(r"\A.*", text).group()

        auction_id = re.search(r"(?:LOT ID: )(\d+)", text).group(1)

        auction_price = re.search(r"(?:€)(\d+.\d+.\d+)", text).group(1)
        auction_price = auction_price.replace(",", "")
        auction_price = float(auction_price)

        date = re.search(r"(?:Sold on |Reserve not met )(.*)", text).group(1)
        date = datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")

        datapoint["auction_id"] = int(auction_id)
        datapoint["name"] = name
        datapoint["auction_price"] = auction_price
        datapoint["date"] = date

        clean_data.append(datapoint)
        
    return clean_data

def read_id_from_database() -> list:
    """Connects to the MySQL Database and returns a list of all existing auction_ids."""
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(**database_credentials)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    SQL = """SELECT auction_id FROM database"""
    cursor.execute(SQL)
    ids = cursor.fetchall()
    existing_ids = [id[0] for id in ids]

    return existing_ids


def select_new_datapoints(data : list) -> list:
    """Takes a list of dictionaries. Compares the auction_id with a list of existing auction IDs.
        Returns a list of all dictionaries with new auction IDs"""
    existing_ids = read_id_from_database()
    new_datapoints = []
    for element in data:
        if int(element["auction_id"]) not in existing_ids:
            new_datapoints.append(element)
    return new_datapoints
```

Clean_data extracts relevant information from a webdriver object on auction items. Every item is represented as a dictionary called datapoint. Every key-value-pair in this dictionary is one bit of information. The function returns a list of dictionaries.

read_id_from_database just returns a list of all auction_ids which are already stored in my database.

select_new_datapoints checks whether an item on the Clean_data list has an id which is already in my database by comparing its id to the list provided by read_id_from_database. If the id does not already exist, the item gets added to the new_datapoint list.

```
for element in data:
        if int(element["auction_id"]) not in existing_ids:
            new_datapoints.append(element)
```

Those items get added to my database later on.

The problem is now, that the select_new_datapoints method does not work. It always keeps all items, despite most or even all of the IDs being already present in my database.

I already checked this by printing the IDs from clean_data and existing_ids into a csv file and comparing them visually:

[CSV File](https://easyupload.io/2x8gqy)

Both lists are identical, meaning the read_id_from_database should return an empty new_datapoints list. However, the read_id_from_database instead returns a list with 226 elements, meaning something is going wring here:

```
new_datapoints = []
    for element in data:
        if int(element["auction_id"]) not in existing_ids:
            new_datapoints.append(element)
    return new_datapoints
```

I assume that for some reason

```
    if int(element["auction_id"]) not in existing_ids:
        new_datapoints.append(element)
```

always evaluates to TRUE and therefore all elements get appended.
I was unable to find out why this is since

```
if int(element["auction_id"]) not in existing_ids:
```

Should work as intended and my csv showed me that every element's id is already in the existing_ids list. I also already checked the types of the data I am comparing they are both int.

Comment: `id` is a built-in name in Python, you shouldn't call anything that. `[id[0] for id in ids]` could be problematic because of that. Also, have you used a debugger or print statements to check the contents of `existing_ids` and make sure it has what's expected, including the expected type? Have you checked what `element["auction_id"]` resolves to, including the type?

Comment: @RandomDavis the name `id` shouldn't be a problem

Comment: What is the database schema for the database table? You might not be getting integers back from `read_id_from_database`

Comment: @JackSmith This was indeed the problem. The Id's column in my database was integer. However for some reason in python I got them back as a string. I now converted them again explicitely into integers in python.